# How to make sense of this standalone infinitive? (Metamorphoses 1.601—603)

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, metamorphoses, ovidius, infinitive

For starters, I haven't finished translating this short passage yet, so I would be grateful if you refrain from giving the full translation. (And if it's hard to answer the question without doing so, then maybe a useful hint would suffice.)

I wanted to know, what exactly is the perfect active infinitive *fecisse* doing here?

> Interea medios Iuno despexit in Argos
>   et noctis faciem nebulas **fecisse** volucres
>   sub nitido mirata die, [...]
>
> Metamorphoses 1.601–603

At first I thought, "indirect discourse!" But I don't see any verbs that introduce indirect discourse.  It's also clearly not a complementary infinitive. With these ruled out, I'm pretty much out of ideas. Perhaps it could be a historical/poetical form of the verb, but I doubt it. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I added some tags and slightly redid formatting. Did you know that you can break a row with two spaces at the end of a line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Edited drastically from previous version after several rereadings of the passage.)

*Mirata* means *mirata est*.
It is not a plain participle, but a perfect form of a deponent verb.
It governs an ACI, whose infinitive is *fecisse*.
(And even if you read *mirata* as a plain participle, it can still govern an ACI.)

The next clause also has ACI: *non esse nec remitti sensit* (simplified).

As requested, I refrain from giving a fuller translation or analysis.
If you are still stuck, please ask for more details.

Comment: Oh! I think I get it now. Thank you. By the way, do you think these kinds of questions are okay? (Where the author requests a pointer or a hint, but not the full translation?)

Comment: @ktm5124, I think questions like this are perfectly fine. At [our mathematical cousin site](http://math.stackexchange.com/) asking for hints is encouraged and sometimes apparently preferred to asking for full answers.

Comment: I think *fecisse* is actually governed by *mirata*; *sensit* is in the next clause.

Comment: @TKR That's interesting. How does a past participle govern an infinitive? Could you possibly explain this idea in a separate answer?

Comment: @TKR, that does indeed feel more likely now that I read the passage again. I'll make a small edit, but feel free to add your own answer, too.

Comment: @ktm5124, if the verb *mirari* can govern an infinitive, so can its participles. Compare these: *Scio te cecinisse et cano. Sciens te cecinisse cano.*

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Joonas's answer, I think he is 100% correct that *mirata* is elliptical; ***est* is left out** but must be assumed in order to translate the sentence. The structure is as follows:

> Iuno **despexit** in Argos
>
> et **mirata [est]** nebulas volucres fecisse faciem noctis
>
> nec **sensit** [nebulas] remitti tellure

We have three parallel main clauses here, separated by the coördinating conjunctions *et* and *nec*. Within the second clause, there is an accusative with infinitive that depends on / is governed by the verb *mirata*; the third clause* also contains an a.c.i., depending on *sensit*.

---

In your quotation, *est* must have been left out. The coördinating conjunction *et* forces us to read it as something that is parallel with what came before it; because it cannot be parallel with a single noun or a noun group, or whatever, that came before *et*, it must be parallel with the entire clause before it (*Iuno aspexit...*), which means that it must itself also be a full clause with a finite verb (*mirata est...*).

An English aequivalent would be thus:

> <s>Juno looked down and amazed that ...</s>

It seems clear that *was* must be supplied, or the two parts cannot be properly read together.

If there had been no *et*, then the opposite would have obtained:

> *Iuno despexit in Argos
>
> *mirata nebulas volucres fecisse faciem noctis

The English aequivalent would be thus:

> Juno looked down, amazed that ...

The participle would have had to be dependent on the previous clause, and one (full) clause can only depend on another clause (= be subordinate to it) if it is introduced with a subordinating conjunction or a relative pronoun, which is absent here. It follows that *mirata* could not have been a full clause, and the whole phrase would have been just a participial phrase (a participle with some arguments), just as in the English example.

---

As to whether participles can govern infinitives and indirect speech, the answer is yes. **A participle is both an adjective and a verb** at the same time. Externally, it is an adjective, since it must normally agree with a noun or pronoun (although those can be implicit—but that is also the case with adjectives). That's why participles have the same endings as adjectives.

> *laudo canem mordentem* = I praise the biting dog
>
> *curo canem vulneratum* = I care for the wounded dog

Internally, however, it is a verb, which means that it can often have the same arguments that any other verb can—arguments that depend on it / are governed by it.

> *laudo canem mordentem inimicos* = I praise a dog biting enemies / that bites enemies (a direct object normally occurs only with verbs)
>
> *curo canem vulneratum ab inimico* = I care for a dog wounded by an enemy / that is wounded by an enemy (*ab* "by" normally occurs only with verbs)

So *mirata* can govern an a.c.i. just like any other verb.

---

*) By "clause" I always mean a full clause, i.e. a finite verb with its dependencies—the conventional meaning of the word *clause* as something closed off and complete.

Comment: Good answer! You can break a row with two spaces at the end of a line, Did you want to leave the vertical spaces between the lines in your first quote box? Also, this looks like a typo: "That's why participles have the same endings as participles."